# change Ctrl+L shortcut to clear screen

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I am using Ubuntu desktop and type clear command each time I want to have a clean sheet. I recently found that there is a shortcut for this which is Ctrl+L. However this doesn't function exactly the same as `clear`. It acts like
`clear -x`.
How can I make it act exactly like `clear`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to your ~/.bashrc

```
bind -x '"\C-l":clear'
```

binds key ctrl+l to clear

if you want more commands to run you can separate them with ;

Comment: Oh thank you, this works perfectly. What a headache it was searching for a solution. Everywhere I read they had mentioned that Ctrl+L doesn't behave the same as "clear" but they didn't mention how to make a keyboard shortcut to do exactly as "clear"